# Configuring Vercel build

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel

My site has a bunch of static files in the root directory, but it also has a subdirectory that contains a React/Vite project. I'd like to build these both correctly, and I aim to redirect the root page to the portfolio index page. Currently my file structure looks like this:

```
/
 a.html
 b.js
 c.html
 portfolio/
     index.html
     stuff.js
```

I attempted to configure Vercel as shown below (vercel.json), but it shows a fully empty build output, leading to a 404 not found when trying to visit the site.

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "/",
      "use": "@vercel/static",
      "config": { "cleanUrls": true }
    },
    {
      "src": "/portfolio",
      "use": "@vercel/node",
      "config": { "zeroConfig": true }
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    
    {
      "src": "/",
      "dest": "/portfolio/index.html"
    },
    { "handle": "filesystem" },
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "/portfolio/index.html"
    },
    {
      "src": "/portfolio/.*",
      "dest": "/portfolio/index.html"
    },
    {
      "src": "/portfolio/.*",
      "dest": "/portfolio/$1"
    }
  ]
}
```